# XML Comparison(String) in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have two XML strings in two separate tables.

```
**ROOT**

**Node ID=** 1

**name** vignesh **/name**

**street** 1211 **/street**

**/Node**


**Node ID=** 2

**name** ram **/name**

**street** 333 **/street**

**/Node**

**/ROOT**
```

---

```
**ROOT**

**Node ID=** 1

**name** newbie **/name**

**street** 121223 **/street**

**/Node**


**Node ID=** 2

**name** pro **/name**

**street** 445**/street**

**/Node**

**/ROOT**
```

Please help me to find the comparison between these two XMLs in **SQL** Server and give result as Old value and New value for both ID1 and ID2(Node).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you out . i build a proper XML structure by considering your XML data.

```
DECLARE @XMLString1 XML =
'<ROOT>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>1</NodeID>
    <name>vignesh </name>
    <street>1211</street>
  </Nodes>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>2</NodeID>
    <name>ram</name>
    <street>333</street>
  </Nodes>
</ROOT>' ,

@XMLString2 XML =
'<ROOT>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>1</NodeID>
    <name>newbie </name>
    <street>121223</street>
  </Nodes>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>2</NodeID>
    <name>pro</name>
    <street>445</street>
  </Nodes>
</ROOT>'

SELECT @XMLString1,@XMLString2

;WITH XMLDATA1 AS 
    (
    SELECT T.X.value('NodeID[1]','varchar(50)') AS NODEID,
           T.X.value('name[1]','varchar(50)') AS NAME,
           T.X.value('street[1]','varchar(50)') AS STREET
     FROM @XMLString1.nodes('/ROOT/Nodes')T(X)
    )
,XMLDATA2 AS 
    (
    SELECT T.X.value('NodeID[1]','varchar(50)') AS NODEID,
           T.X.value('name[1]','varchar(50)') AS NAME,
           T.X.value('street[1]','varchar(50)') AS STREET
     FROM @XMLString2.nodes('/ROOT/Nodes')T(X)
    )
    SELECT X1.NODEID,X1.NAME AS OLD_NAME,X2.NAME AS NEW_NAME , X1.STREET AS OLD_STREET , X2.STREET AS NEW_STREET
    FROM XMLDATA1 X1
    INNER JOIN XMLDATA2 X2 ON X1.NODEID=X2.NODEID
```

Comment: I am getting XML String as input from user itself. So i don't know the name of the tags and what if there are 100 XML Tags. @mahesh-kola

Comment: Do you get the different tags every time.? or else those 100+ tags are fixed ?

Comment: I get different tags every time. Not fixed one.

Comment: Though you get the different tags every time but will you be having the same parent tag ? i.e;  `Root tag` and also could you please post some kind of your sample XML for our understanding .

Comment: DECLARE @XMLString1 XML =
'<ROOT>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>1</NodeID>
    <name>vignesh </name>
    <street>1211</street>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
  </Nodes>
  <Nodes>
    <NodeID>2</NodeID>
    <name>ram</name>
    <street>333</street>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
  </Nodes>
</ROOT>'

Comment: Parent Node is same for all XMLS.. but child nodes may differ. @mahesh-kola